# How do I create progress indicator like in Android Market app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to create such dialog for my app:

[image]

Is that a DialogFragment?

Comment: Look at the answer to this question: [Loading screen in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985171/loading-screen-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html), combined with the 'Loading' text in a simple LinearLayout (horizontal orientation).

You can probably do it with the fragment API, but depending on your needs including it in a RelativeLayout (via layout_centerInParent) and hidden with `setVisible(View.GONE)` or shown with `setVisible(View.VISIBLE)` as requested could work just as well.

Comment: Yes, I thought about Fragments API, but wondered if it was standart dialog fragment.